# Installing NASA CEA on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install NASA CEA on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

But I'm stuck to this point:

```
  Update Unix environment variables such as JDK_HOME or JRE_HOME, 
  CLASSPATH, and PATH: 
  In csh,the Unix environment variables are modified with the setenv command
        setenv CLASSPATH path1:path2
        setenv JDK_HOME /usr/jdk
        setenv PATH $JDK_HOME/bin:${PATH}:.
               Note That: The DOT . is necessary.

  In sh, the Unix environment variables are modified with these commands:
        CLASSPATH = path1:path2
        export CLASSPATH

        JDK_HOME = /usr/jdk
        export JDK_HOME

        PATH = $JDK_HOME/bin:${PATH}:.
              Note That: The DOT . is necessary.
        export PATH
```

I have no idea about how to deal with the instructions written there. Could you suggest how to proceed in ubuntu?

Thank You

Comment: Sorry. It's not our responsibility to leave this site to review the links you've provided in order to try and figure out what you're asking. Please place the **relevant** parts of the information here, in your question itself. Having to leave the site to find out what you're asking means that if the links aren't available in the future, your question is of no use to future readers here. Questions must contain all relevant details here, in the question itself.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you for your comment. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it on Ubuntu 15.10 and it works well. Maybe it will work on 14.04 LTS. Don't worry about these commands in the instructions. Try this:
- unpack the three "zips" on a directory, as example: CEAexec.
- in the directory, and using the Terminal, do the command line:

> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/home/blablabla/CEAexec
> ```

Attention: ***/home/blablabla/CEAexec*** is the path of the directory CEAexec. This command says to JAVA where is CEA. For you must not do this all times that you run CEA, you need to write or modify the batch script.  I don't know how do this.
- in the same directory (CEAexec) do the command line:

> ```
> ./runCEA.sh
> ```

If you receive an error message, maybe you should update the Fortran executables.  For this, you need have an fortran package installed, as example: gfortran.
You can do as an instruction for install CEA on OS Mac that I found on web (http://spase.stanford.edu/CEA_files/cea_how_to_gfortran_snowleo.pdf). It worked on Linux. I copied and pasted following, in the case of broken link (I thank to J.Zimmerman).
To do that, move to the CEA installation directory and type the following code:

> ```
> gfortran cea2.f    
> mv a.out FCEA2   
> gfortran  b1b2b3.f    
> mv a.out b1b2b3    
> gfortran syntax.f   
> mv a.out syntax
> ```

If during this process you get a long string of warning messages about feature deleted: goto ... it’s bogus and safe to ignore. Now you should have new executable files, but you’ll still need to get new library files. To do that, type:

> ```
> FCEA2    
> trans    
> FCEA2    
> thermo    
> FCEA2    
> cea2
> ```

Note that each time you type FCEA2 you should get a statement asking for the input filename. You should now be all set. To try it out, type `./runCEA.sh` in the CEA installation directory,and try loading an example file and executing it.  OK, I'm not a linux expert but these worked for me and for my students. Good luck!